# Why is half of my UV mesh off of the grid, and how do I fix it? [3DS Max/Blender]

Tags: texture, 3ds-max, blender

I've got two models, each with their own texture, that I'm trying to combine into one model with one texture so I can mod it into a game. I've tried following tutorials on how to bake textures into one, but when I join the models and look at the UV editor the body of the model is off the grid, like this:

[image]

This makes it really hard to follow tutorials, since all of the ones I've seen have everything nicely located within the grid, and I've tried in Blender and 3DS Max. None of my attempts have resulted in a texture that lines up with the model in the correct way, and I think this has something to do with it. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not sure if you know this, but there's a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)